# variable declaration does not work

Tags: shell-script

I have the below script in my system:

```
#!/bin/sh

LASTFILES=`find /var/log -mtime -1 -iname *.csv`

KEYWORDS="MD AG GA"

countMD="0"
countAG="0"
countGA="0"

for i in $LASTFILES ; do
    for a in $KEYWORDS ; do
        count_$a=`grep -a $date $i | grep -i "\"$a\"" | grep smsMoBilling | wc -l`
        count$a=`expr $count$a + $count_$a`
         done
done
```

It doesn't work when I run it.

```
./test.sh: line 35: count_MD=37: command not found
expr: non-numeric argument
./test.sh: line 36: countMD=: command not found
```

What is the matter with the variable declared? Could you help me?

Comment: Your listing is incomplete. Line 35 is beyond that loop.

Comment: That, and the first error quotes count_MD while you have countMD in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> count_$a=`grep -a $date $i | grep -i "\"$a\"" | grep smsMoBilling | wc -l`
> ```

There's a syntax error here. In an assignment, you need to put a variable name before the `=`. A longer piece of text that expands to a variable name isn't supported.

Instead of generating variable names from pieces, use associative arrays indexed by the variable part. This requires a shell that supports associative arrays: ksh93, bash or zsh. While you're at it, don't parse the output of `find` (it might work here, but it doesn't work in general when file names may contain whitespace or `\[*?`). Use shell globbing and arrays instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
CSV_FILES=(/var/log/**/*.[Cc][Ss][Vv])
KEYWORDS=(MD AG GA)
typeset -A count
for i in "${CSV_FILES[@]}" ; do
    for a in "${KEYWORDS[@]}" ; do
        count[$a]+=$(grep -a "$date" "$i" | grep -i "\"$a\"" | grep smsMoBilling | wc -l)
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem here is quoting. Also, I would use an associative array (and `bash` instead of `sh`) instead of trying to concatenate the variable names (that might be possible but I haven't been able to get it to work). The details of your errors probably depend on the specific file names you have but try this instead:

```
#!/bin/env bash

LASTFILES=`find /var/log -mtime -1 -iname "*.csv"`

KEYWORDS="MD AG GA"

countMD="0"
countAG="0"
countGA="0"
declare -A count1;
declare -A count2;

for i in "$LASTFILES" ; do
    for a in "$KEYWORDS" ; do
         count1[$a]=`grep -a "$date" "$i" | grep -i "\"$a\"" | grep -c smsMoBilling`
         count2[$a]=$((${count2[$a]}+${count1[$a]}));
    done
done
```